# Xcode clean build folder command not working

Tags: xcode

Not sure what happened but suddenly, my xcode clean build folder option under Product -> Clean Build Folder no longer works. Instead it gives me an error:

Could not delete `/Users/...build` because it was not created by the build system.

Is there a way I can reset the xcode settings? Or does someone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: It looks like a problem with file permissions, try restarting Xcode or changing the file permissions.  `chmod -R 755  ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

Comment: Unfortunately that still did not work for me

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. I can clean the build folder from xcode but I get the same error message as you when I attempt to do it from the command line